# How are Agile development practices affected by a pervasive system change?

Tags: agile

When a large system developed by Agile process requires a sudden large-scale change that affects most everything, what is the best way to go about it using Agile? Does the iterative part change at this point?

For example, what if a decision is made to make a centralized system a distributed one? Or choose another large pervasive example.

Arguably large changes should have been planned for, but it's never a perfect world which is one of the reasons Agile exists, so assume that suddenly a major change is introduced that shakes the foundation.

**Edit to summarize solutions:**

- It's incremental all the way no matter how large or small the change may be.

Comment: Hypotheticals -- like this -- are nearly impossible to answer.  There are too many things we're allowed to assume that you can then reject as not being part of *your* assumptions.  "choose another large pervasive example" allows us to define anything we want as "large" and "pervasive" and none of our definitions could possibly match yours.  Focus and specifics help.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm focusing on the Agile process in general and how it is used, and there are always general answers to be had even if the answer has to provide some of its own context. I don't have a specific example right now but appreciate the insight for when I do.

Comment: It's incremental creation of the software.  But sometimes its not incremental changes of the original software its incremental creation of a new architecture where you then plugin in what you can of the old system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Does the iterative part change at this point?"

Never.

No matter how "pervasive" the change appears to be, you still have to work incrementally, in iterations you can manage.

You still have to prioritize the changes and make them in a way that will continue to pass unit tests and can be released when needed.

You may, for example, find that fixing 80% of the system is sufficient, and you may release.  Or may be required to fix 100% of the system before releasing.

You still work incrementally.  In sprints.  Irrespective of when you release.

Comment: +1 All large scale changes are merely a series of small scale changes in disguise. Besides, isn't the largest change the time you created your project from an empty text file?

Comment: The *whole point* of Agile is to adapt to change. If you throw out Agile as soon as you have to adapt to change, you are doing something terribly wrong. (OTOH, let's not forget that adapting the development process *itself* to change *is* being Agile.)

Comment: kindda.

starting from a car and morphing to a plane is going to get you quite a different thing from starting from 0 and morphing to a plane.

When the architecture is quite different from the original, you need to consider quite carefully how you want to change.

Comment: @Keith Nicholas:  The Agile answer to "how you want to change" is "Incrementally".  How you want to release this may be "all at once".  But you have to manage the dependencies and the intellectual effort.  The best approach is to follow the basic Agile manifesto value statements so that the change is done well.

Answer (score 1):

Agile has no magic answers.

There's a number of approaches :-

Plot a path of reasonably incremental changes to change the system from one archtecture to another.  If you have reasonably well factored code, you should be ditching the code that is made redundant by the change and keeping stuff thats independent of the change.

Another approach if things are really different, start a parallel development of components for the new system.

Or, start new and steal as much as you can from the old project.

Depends how BIG the change really is.